# How to make item accessible in class method

Tags: python, django

I have the following model class:

```
class ItemInstance(models.Model):

    TITLE = 0
    COLLECTION = 1
    TVSERIES = 2
```

This allows me to do:

```
item = ItemInstance.objects.all()[0]
item.TITLE ==> 0
```

But not this:

```
cls = ItemInstance
cls.TITLE ==> error
```

How would I enable these `vars` to be available for a `@classmethod`?

Comment: What is the result of dir(ItemInstance)? I'm guessing django is doing something to mess with your class variables, because in normal python (not subclassing models.Model) that'd be fine.

Comment: That's correct -- it does work, it was actually a typo on my end. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Everything on the subject here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python